# SQL - Sort Select from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following row from a table in MSSQL

```
 Person | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4

 John   |   4    |    7   |   1    |   2
```

I want this row sorted according to the values as shown below.

```
 Person | value2 | value1 | value4 | value3

 John   |   7    |    4   |   2    |   1
```

May be I'm asking a stupid question , I want the column names to be sorted according to the values in those column.

I know that this can be achieved using query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
ORDER BY value2, value1, value4, value3 DESC
```

But when I change the any column value, I have to change the query to get the result sorted.

Please help...

Comment: I think you should clarify if you want to order rows or columns. It is not clear.

Comment: You can't really without dynamic SQL as the column list / position is defined at query compilation time.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: And what if another row has `Peter|1|2|3|4` ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question with what the result should be for the following SQL statement (executes in all environments):  
WITH DATA AS
     (SELECT 'Brian' PERSON, 1 a, 2 b, 3 c, 4 d
        FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Tom', 4 a, 3 b, 2 c, 1 d
        FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'John', 2 a, 3 b, 1 c, 2 d
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM DATA

Answer (score 4):

```
-- sample data
declare @t table
(
    person varchar(50),
    value1 int,
    value2 int,
    value3 int,
    value4 int
)

insert into @t select 'John', 4, 7, 1, 2
insert into @t select 'Name1', 14, 7, 1, 16
insert into @t select 'Name2', 24, 8, 1, 2

-- query
select
    person, v1 = [1], v2 = [2], v3 = [3], v4 = [4]
from
(
    select person, rn = row_number() over(partition by person order by a desc), a 
    from @t t1
    unpivot 
    (
        a for b in (value1, value2, value3, value4)
    ) t2
) t1
pivot
(
    max(a) for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) t2
```

Comment: +1 But this doesn't give the (frankly bizarre) desired results where the OP wants the column names shuffled around not just the values.

Comment: +1 this is the only answer that actually **answers** what OP asked. But the requirement is weird indeed

Answer (score 1):

unless I'm missing something, you should just append 'order by person, value2, value1, value4, value3' at the end of your select statement.

Comment: No, he wants to re-order the *columns*, not the rows. (Yeah I know... it's strange...)

Comment: aha, yes I see that now ... strange indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT Person, Value2, Value1, Value4, Valuer
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY value2, value1, value4, value3 DESC
```